# FormHandler in the Bucket

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, react-native

So, i'm trying to set this string to get uri of the image and the article, but i'm using positions and setting new key to create a new entry... How can i set this form with uri of the image? I'm not set yet the getDownload() method.

I already had the upload and it's working, now i need to storage in the bucket.

```
 submitFormHandler = () => {
        console.log("FormHandler: " + this.state.message)
        let isFormValid = true;
        let dataToSubmit = {};
        const formCopy = this.state.form;

        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        for (let key in formCopy) {
          isFormValid = isFormValid && formCopy[key].valid;
          dataToSubmit[key] = this.state.form[key].value;
        }

        if (isFormValid, user) {
          this.setState({
            loading: true
          });

          getTokens((value) => {
            const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/').child(imageSource.uri)
            const dateNow = new Date();
            const expiration = dateNow.getTime();
            const form = {
              ...dataToSubmit,
              uid: value[3][1]
            }

            if (expiration > value[2][1]) {
              this.props.autoSignIn(value[1][1]).then(() => {
                setTokens(this.props.User.userData, () => {

                  this.props.addArticle(form, this.props.User.userData.token).then(() => {
                    this.setState({ modalSuccess: true })
                  })
                })
              })
            } else {
              this.props.addArticle(form, value[0][1]).then(() => {
                this.setState({ modalSuccess: true })
              })
            }
          })

        } else {
          let errorsArray = [];

          for (let key in formCopy) {
            if (!formCopy[key].valid) {
              errorsArray.push(formCopy[key].errorMsg)
            }
          }

          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            upload: true,
            hasErrors: true,
            modalVisible: true,
            errorsArray
          })
        }
      }

      showErrorsArray = (errors) => (
        errors ?
          errors.map((item, i) => (
            <Text key={i} style={styles.errorItem}> - {item}</Text>
          ))
          : null
      )

      clearErrors = () => {
        this.setState({
          hasErrors: false,
          modalVisible: false,
          errorsArray: []
        })
      }

      resetScreen = () => {
        const formCopy = this.state.form;

        for (let key in formCopy) {
          formCopy[key].valid = false;
          formCopy[key].value = "";
        }

        this.setState({
          modalSuccess: false,
          hasErrors: false,
          errorsArray: [],
          loading: false
        })

        this.props.resetArticle();

      }
```

Comment: In its current formulation, your question is hard to understand. Also, the code seems to contain many lines unrelated to your question. Could you try to make the  problem clearer and more focussed?

Comment: yes, i haven't put every thing, maybe you could understand more in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661873/how-to-softcode-firebase-storage-image-urls , maybe you understand better.

Comment: sorry for my mistake... this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377751/how-to-get-the-uri-of-an-uploaded-image